# Hide the URL parameters that are sent from a node server

Tags: node.js, forms, hide, html

I send parameters from a html form to my node js server.

[Picture Form](https://preview.ibb.co/mZXkWc/formulario.png)

In my server I receive the data in the next way:

[Picture Server](https://preview.ibb.co/fARvWc/servidor.png)

So far all is good, but now I want to open a web page without the parameters that I have received before,in other way I want that the parameters are not visible in the URL for the users, in the moment that I open a page using “res.redirect” are seen in the browser as:

```
https://miDominio.com/room.html?idUsuario=user1&nombreRoom=room1
```

and I would like that the parameters that I pass are not to visible. I want the next way:

```
https://miDominio.com/room.html
```

Do you know how can I do this ?

Comment: I think you can just use javascript for this since the server side just redirects you but you can do that in the front end. However, that will not hide the link. So then, use ajax to get the page room.html?id.... And then display that page using jquery to a div. Let know if need more specific help and will try to help.

Comment: essentially what you are asking for is server side rendering, construct the data on the server and send the formatted html